# why logstash "multiline" filter didn't work correctly?

Tags: logstash, multiline, elastic-stack

This is my configuration file :

```
input{
 redis{
      data_type => "list"
      key => "aas-redis-logback"
      host => "my redis host"
      port => "6379"
      password => "my redis password"
    #  threads => 5
   }
 stdin{}    
}

filter{ 
    multiline{
          pattern => "^\[AAS\]" 
          negate => true  
          what => "previous"  
     }

}

output{
  elasticsearch{
      hosts  => "168.2.8.88:9200"
      index  => "0814-multi-test"
  }
  stdout{codec => rubydebug}
}
```

and this is my log file:
[image]

And this is my output:
[image]

It seems like the "pattern" of multiline filter is not work, all of the log message have been put together.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change true to "true".
Then it becomes

```
multiline{
      pattern => "^\[AAS\]" 
      negate => "true" 
      what => "previous"  
 }
```

And it works correctly.